# If $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\geq n^2$ then $\exists j:x_j>2$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> If $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\geq n$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\geq n^2$ then $\exists j:x_j>2$.

An interesting mathematical problem. I know that the second sum comes from Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality but it doesn't help at all. I have tried to create a function $$f(x_1,\dots ,x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2- n^2$$ and see what happens with it but I didn't succeed. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Sorry about that, I have just updated the question. I believe the problems wants us to prove that for any set $\{x_1, \dots , x_n \}$ there must be at least one $x_j > 2$ that satisfies the conditions.

Comment: I believe you are missing a required condition: if $n=2$, $x_1=x_2=1,5$ we have $\sum_1^2 1,5^2=4,5>2^2$ but $1,5<2$.

Comment: @Cleto if $x_i=x$ constant we can take $x=\sqrt{n}$ and it fails for $n=1,2,3,4$. So we need at least $n\ge 5$.

Comment: @zwim you're right. More than that, thinking by contradiction: if we have $x_i<2$ for all $i$, we have $\sum_1^n x_i^2 <4n$ and $4n \geq n^2$ implies $0<n<4$.